# 2D "Heat Seeker" Algorithm

Tags: vectors, conic-sections, kinematics

I'm working on a 2D game where one of the weapons available to the player is the classic "heat seeker" projectile.  Once fired, it finds a path to the target.  But finding that path has turned out to be really difficult, which makes me think I must be overlooking something obvious.

The only inputs to the algorithm are:

- $\vec v_0$ = the initial velocity of the projectile (the player's velocity)
- $p_{player}$ = the player's position (which is the initial position of the projectile)
- $p_{target}$ = the target's position, which is stationary

For simplicity, I assume the projectile just has a fixed acceleration vector, $\vec a$.  There are infinitely many paths the projectile could take to hit the target, but using a fixed acceleration makes the path a parabola, which I thought would be easiest to solve.

So there's one additional input:

- $\left \| \vec a \right \|$ = the scalar magnitude of the projectile's acceleration (i.e. how much "thrust" does it have, for example $10 m/s^2$)

Given these four inputs, I believe there is exactly one parabola that passes through both $p_{player}$ and $p_{target}$.  The goal is to find $\vec a$, and I already know its length $\left \| \vec a \right \|$, so the only thing left to solve for is the angle of $\vec a$.

Can the parabola (and hence $\vec a$) be found by solving the plain old kinematic equations (below)?  Maybe by plugging in $p_{target}$ and working back to find the required acceleration?
$$\vec a(t) = \vec a = constant$$
$$\vec v(t) = \vec v_0 + \vec a t$$
$$\vec p(t) = p_{player} + \vec v_0 t + \frac{1}{2}\vec a t^2$$

Comment: I would think the point in a game is not to be able to solve the path in closed form (which you can do with a parabola), but simply to hit the target. For example, the missile could first rotate to face the target and then use [proportional navigation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proportional_navigation) to guide it there. The ability to steer means you don't have to lay in the perfect interception path right away. And a missile that steers would *look* like it was a "heat seeking" missile.

Comment: @DavidK – I agree, something more simple is probably a better solution as far as a "game development" discussion.  But the accepted answer really is the right answer in terms of pure math.  So I'm keeping that as the accepted answer since this is a math forum and not a gamedev forum.

Comment: I agree. That is why my comment is a comment and not an answer. I'm sure nobody here minds neat little math problem like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $v$ be the initial velocity of the projectile, $A$ its initial position, $B$ the target's position and $\alpha$ the angle between $v$ and ray $AB$ (see figure below). We must find the angle $\beta$ between the acceleration (of fixed magnitude $a$) and $AB$ so that the parabola passes through $B$. Note that $\beta$ is also the angle between $AB$ and the direction of the axis of the parabola.

We can decompose $v$ as the sum $v_x+v_y$ of vectors parallel to $AB$ and to $a$. The time taken by the projectile to go from $A$ to $H$ (which is the point on the parabola where the tangent is parallel to $AB$) can be computed as $v_y/a$ but also as $s/v_x$, where I set $s=AM={1\over2}AB$.
That leads to the equality
$$
v_xv_y=as.
$$

From the sine law one also gets:
$$
v_x=v{\sin(\alpha+\beta)\over\sin\beta},\quad
v_y=v{\sin\alpha\over\sin\beta},
$$
and inserting these into the preceding equality we obtain the final equation:
$$
\sin^2\alpha\cos\beta+\sin\alpha\cos\alpha\sin\beta={as\over v^2}\sin^2\beta.
$$
One can extract $\cos\beta$ from there and insert the result into
$\cos^2\beta+\sin^2\beta=1$ to find a quartic equation in $\sin\beta$.
Explicit solutions can be found with the aid of a software, but they are too long to be of any help: in practice I think it's better to solve the equation numerically.

[image]

Comment: I worked through something similar (I decomposed a into a_x and a_y instead of using the angle ) and also ended up with a quartic equation.  It took a couple of days but I was able to simplify the quartic enough to put it into code, and I can confirm that it does actually work in game.  The flight paths look very realistic.